# Как побороть дорвея. Гугл

Tags: seo

друзья!

Все, кто разбирается в seo, прошу Вашего совета.

Есть региональная небольшая ниша в которой много лет все было спокойно. Сайты конкурировали между собой, менялись местами, в общем, ничего особенного.

Но полтора месяца назад один из конкурентов сделал очень дерзкую, неправильную, но нужно отдать ему должное, интересную вещь.

Примерно, 7-9 месяцами ранее он создал 2 сайта. Эти сайты состоят из 1 страницы с текстом на 54 000 знаков, причем 3-4k знаков - это более-менее нормальный текст, а остальные 50 000 знаков (!!!!!!) тупо перечисление ключей, вот так:

> ключ 1
>
> ключ 2
>
> ключ 3 ...

При этом эти 2 сайта имеют одинаковый текст.

На них он закупил по 20 000 безанкорных ссылок с примерно 1500 доменов (по ahrefs), какие-то китайские форумы и пр., в общем, помойка.

Теперь эти сайты в топе.

**Но он пошел дальше.**

Он создал на крупных тематических сайтах из нишевой тематики статические объявления с текстом также в виде ключей. Далее он закупил на эти страницы по 8 000 ссылок и эти страницы с его объявлением также вылетели в топ.

**Таким образом первые 5-6 позиций топа по самому конкурентному ключу его!!!!**

Очевидно, что это явный спам, поэтому я сообщил об этом в гугл [здесь](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreportform?hl=ru)
Но гугл не отреагировал, сказал, что поставил в очередь.

Есть ли какие-либо способы ускорить реакцию гугла на подобный беспредел? Или что еще можно сделать?

Comment: Вы можете открыть отдельное обсуждение на форуме помощи веб-мастерам Гугл (лучше на английском, но можно и на русском) ( https://support.google.com/webmasters/community ) и сообщить там об этой технологии и перечислить все спамовые урл. Это будет обязательно замечено. Однако я не знаю скорость реакции Гугл на это сообщение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую.